# Memgraph - how to check dataset size after import

Tags: memgraphdb

I am running Memgraph in docker. How can I check the size of my dataset after importing all the data?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Cypher command `SHOW STORAGE INFO;`. If you are using `mgconsole` your output will look like this:

```
mgconsole 1.4
Connected to 'memgraph://127.0.0.1:7687'
Type :help for shell usage
Quit the shell by typing Ctrl-D(eof) or :quit
memgraph> SHOW STORAGE INFO;
+--------------------------------+--------------------------------+
| storage info                   | value                          |
+--------------------------------+--------------------------------+
| "name"                         | "memgraph"                     |
| "vertex_count"                 | 2677                           |
| "edge_count"                   | 11967                          |
| "average_degree"               | 8.94061                        |
| "memory_usage"                 | 538963968                      |
| "disk_usage"                   | 1603427                        |
| "memory_allocated"             | 15096128                       |
| "allocation_limit"             | 8185118720                     |
| "global_isolation_level"       | "SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION"           |
| "session_isolation_level"      | ""                             |
| "next_session_isolation_level" | ""                             |
| "storage_mode"                 | "IN_MEMORY_TRANSACTIONAL"      |
+--------------------------------+--------------------------------+
12 rows in set (round trip in 0.001 sec)
memgraph>
```

And if you use Memgraph Lab you will see something like this

[image: Memgraph Lab query results]

Comment: But what is the value that represents the size of the dataset. disk_usage or memory_usage?
I would assume that it is memory_usage, because as far as I read the dataset is stored in ram.

Comment: The formula approximation of needed memory is: StorageRAMUsage=NumberOfVertices×260B+NumberOfEdges×180B. memory_alocated includes data+indexes+deltas+all other allocations that are needed for Memgraph operation.  memory_usage is the total memory that Memgraph uses (data+libraries).

The docs are available at https://memgraph.com/docs/configuration/server-stats#storage-information